# REST API designe - list of resources and how to reference only one resource from the list

Tags: rest, restful-url

I'm designin a REST API interface and I'm currently in a struggle how to define URI for one of the resources.

Lets say I have a Cars resource `/api/cars`, and if I do a `GET /api/cars/Ford` I will get a list of all cars which are produced by Ford.

Now I want to get all the Ford cars, but only if the model of that cars is Mondeo, so I will do `GET /api/cars/Ford/model/Mondeo`.

This still returns a list of cars, now I want to get specific Ford Mondeo car, and lets say that I can get a specific card by its serial number. Now I will do a GET `/api/cars/Ford/model/Mondeo/serial/1A2A2B`.

Also, lets assume that in this case I cant just get that specific car using only `GET /api/cars/1A2A2B`, since this serial number can be the same for some other car, but different car factory (so one Ford car can have a same serial number as one Peugeot car).

I'm not sure if this is valid URI representation?

At first I had an idea to use composite ID-s, so I would do `GET /api/cars/Ford,Mondeo,1A2A2B` or `GET /api/cars/Ford,1A2A2B` to identify a specific car. Problem with this approach is that I can't define an URI to get all cards defined by a producer and model (`GET /api/cars/Ford,Mondeo`), since the same URI pattern is already defined to get specific car by producer and serial number.

Answer (score 0):

did you consider making an api that is more like a search adding a filtering capabilities to the basic api (just like your database does...)?

for example, i would seriously consider this:

/api/cars?factory=eq=Ford&model=eq=Mondeo&serial=eq=1A2A2B

Comment: Yes I did, but I m not sure that I can use it for resource PATCHING for example...

Comment: i see. i just thought about the GET api. why not use the full address for PUT and PATCH operations: /api/cars/Ford/model/Mondeo/serial/1A2A2B. i assume that the client has all relevant info at that point and/or consider a unique id that the client could use: PUT /api/cars/<unique-id>

Comment: I explained in the answer to the sschrass why the API cant use its own <unique-id> for the resources. Do you think that such URI (/api/cars/Ford/model/Mondeo/serial/1A2A2B) is a valid REST URI or? Because, to me, it doesn't look like a valid URI, I'm not trying to get the model resource or serial resource, I want to get the car resource, and the model and serial are just additional parts of the car ID (which is composite). But I just don't see the why how to use composite ID-s for this particular case.

Comment: can't you create a synthetic id by prefixing the ford id with a ford prefix that is unique? your clients will send you the extended id: <your-prefix><ford-id> and you will parse it and send ford only their id.

Answer (score 0):

On the `id`:

`GET /api/cars` is a resource that lists all cars in your API, but with `1A2A2B` you reference the car by one or more foreign, third-party `id`-schemes and not with an id of your API. So those ids could clash. Maybe Ford even resuses them on occasion?!
So when looking up resources by id, I would make sure to use the id provided by the API itself and in your case make an additional `/serial/1A2A2B`.

Comment: The thing is that the API can't provide its own ID, because the API depends on a third-party system which has the resource and defines it. The API does not hold any information regarding the resource, so it cant generate its own ID-s for the resources. Also, Ford does never reuse the serial ID, third-party system ensures that that ID can uniquely identify the resource under the given car brand.